# Database::RETURN_AFFECTED not working with a select query

Tags: 8, database

I am trying to run a database query and all I want to know is how many rows were found. Trying to use `rowCount()` throws an error because the query is a select query, but it also says to set the return option to `Database::RETURN_AFFECTED` in the options, yet this does not seem to do anything to the return on execute().

Here is the query:

```
  // top of file
  use Drupal\Core\Database\Database;

  $query = \Drupal::database()->select('file_managed', 'f', ['return' => Database::RETURN_AFFECTED]);
  $query->fields('f', ['fid', 'filename', 'status']);
  $query->condition('f.filename', $result->filename);
  $query->condition('f.fid', $result->fid, '!=');
  $rows_found = $query->execute();
```

Looks like when I inspect the query object, the `return` option is being set to 1, when it should be set to 2 which is what the RETURN_AFFECTED constant represents. Am I setting the option wrong?

How can I just get a count of the rows returned?

Comment: `RETURN_AFFECTED` is for write ops (insert/update/delete), nothing is technically "affected" in a select so PDO probably just nudges the value back to `1` because anything else wouldn't make sense in that context. I'd be tempted just to count `$query->execute()->fetchAll()` to be honest

Comment: Okay, the exception error sounded like you would add that flag to get a count for select.